# bash: ffmpeg libx265 prevent output

Tags: linux, ffmpeg

I'd like to use the new codec x265 (libx265) to encode my video collection.

For this I created a lovely bash script under linux which works in general very well! But something is strange:

I prohibit the output of ffmpeg to echo on my own way. With x264 (the "old" one) everything works fine. But as soon as I use x265 I get always this kind of output on my terminal:

```
x265 [info]: HEVC encoder version 1.7
x265 [info]: build info [Linux][GCC 5.1.0][64 bit] 8bpp
x265 [info]: using cpu capabilities: MMX2 SSE2Fast SSSE3 Cache64
x265 [info]: Main profile, Level-2.1 (Main tier)
x265 [info]: Thread pool created using 2 threads
x265 [info]: frame threads / pool features       : 1 / wpp(5 rows)
x265 [info]: Coding QT: max CU size, min CU size : 64 / 8
x265 [info]: Residual QT: max TU size, max depth : 32 / 1 inter / 1 intra
x265 [info]: ME / range / subpel / merge         : hex / 57 / 2 / 2
x265 [info]: Keyframe min / max / scenecut       : 25 / 250 / 40
x265 [info]: Lookahead / bframes / badapt        : 20 / 4 / 2
x265 [info]: b-pyramid / weightp / weightb / refs: 1 / 1 / 0 / 3
x265 [info]: AQ: mode / str / qg-size / cu-tree  : 1 / 1.0 / 64 / 1
x265 [info]: Rate Control / qCompress            : CRF-28.0 / 0.60
x265 [info]: tools: rd=3 psy-rd=0.30 signhide tmvp strong-intra-smoothing
x265 [info]: tools: deblock sao
```

This is the way I encode my video with ffmpeg:

```
ffmpeg -i /input/file -c:v libx265 -c:a copy -loglevel quiet /output/file.mp4 <>/dev/null 2>&1
```

I thought that the

```
<>/dev/null 2>&1
```

and the

```
-loglevel quiet
```

will do this but apparently I'm mistaken.

How can I solve this problem?

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 21, accepted):

#### Solution

You need to add an **additional** parameter
`-x265-params log-level=xxxxx`, as in

```
ffmpeg -i /input/file -c:v libx265 -c:a copy -loglevel quiet -x265-params log-level=quiet \
        /output/file.mp4  <>/dev/null 2>&1
```

Note that, while the FFmpeg option is `-loglevel`,
the x25 option is `log-level`, with a **`-`** between `log` and `level`;
see the x265 [Command Line Options](https://x265.readthedocs.io/en/stable/cli.html#logging-statistic-options) documentation.

---

#### Explanation

The FFmpeg command you wrote *should* have worked
(see: [ffmpeg documentation](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg.html#Generic-options));
however, it looks like FFmpeg doesn't tell the x265 encoder
to use the loglevel you're telling FFmpeg to use.

So, assuming you want to the whole FFmpeg command to run quietly
(i.e., suppress the messages
from both the main FFmpeg program and the x265 encoder),
you need to explicitly set the log level options for both of them.

Analogously, if you have an FFmpeg command that looks like this:

```
ffmpeg -loglevel error -stats -i "inputfile.xyz" -c:v libx265 -x265-params parameter1=value:parameter2=value outputfile.xyz
```

You can add the `log-level=error` option
to the list of x265-params like this:

```
ffmpeg -loglevel error -stats -i "inputfile.xyz" -c:v libx265 -x265-params log-level=error:parameter1=value:parameter2=value …
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. That is the solution I searched for! Even if my answer comes a bit too late I guess ^^

Comment: My personal preference is to view progress and important errors if there are any. Additionally, since I'm exporting to x265, I need this extra flag. I personally consider this a bug, and the loglevel should pertain to everything, but it's real nice to know to suppress it effectively and correctly. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

`<>/dev/null` will only connect standard input and output to `/dev/null`, and `2>&1` is applied *after* `<>/dev/null`, effectively doing nothing.

Changing it to
`>/dev/null 2>&1`
will do what you want.

Comment: Thanks! That solves the problem. But you have a mistake in your answer: I wrote `2>&1` and not `1>&2` but anyway.. it works :)